# Flask: flask_wtf CSRFProtect yields Bad Request The CSRF session token is missing

Tags: python, session, nginx, flask, flask-wtforms

I am trying to configure CSRF protection on my web app and I cannot seem to figure out FLASK_WTF CSRFProtect

I am initializing my app with

```
from flask import (Flask, g, jsonify, redirect, render_template, request,
                   url_for)
from flask_wtf.csrf import CSRFProtect

csrf = CSRFProtect()

def create_app():
    ...
    ...
    csrf.init_app(app)

    app.app_context().push()

    return app
```

I am also setting `app.config["SECRET_KEY"]` and `app.config["WTF_CSRF_SECRET_KEY"]` within the create_app function.

All of my forms have `<input type="hidden" name="csrf_token" value="{{ csrf_token() }}" />`.

I have read on other posts about using Flask.Form but I am not doing this, rather just grabbing the POST data from the request.form dict.

On POST, I get the following error message:

```
Bad Request

The CSRF session token is missing.
```

Locally everything runs fine but when I run my code from my gunicorn, nginx enviornment it fails. Any ideas? Do I need to set the SERVER_NAME attribute?

EDIT:

Upon request, the CSRF_TOKEN is actually sent after inspecting the headers.

Hmm, the form csrf_token in source seems to be different than the token sent with POST

EDIT:

I added configuration variables for flask_wtf in my create_app function and it is still not working:

```
app.config["WTF_CSRF_SECRET_KEY"] = "same_as_secret_key"
app.config["WTF_CSRF_FIELD_NAME"] = "csrf_token"
app.config['WTF_CSRF_ENABLED'] = True
app.config["WTF_CSRF_TIME_LIMIT"] = None  # valid throughout life of session
if debug:
    app.config["SESSION_COOKIE_SECURE"] = False
else:
    app.config["SESSION_COOKIE_SECURE"] = True
app.config["REMEMBER_COOKIE_SECURE"] = True
```

Could this have something to do with my nginx configuration?

Comment: Your app factory pattern differs a little from the docs [here](https://flask-wtf.readthedocs.io/en/stable/csrf.html). In theirs, they instantiate the `csrf` instance outside of the `create_app()` function, without passing `app` to the constructor, and just call `csrf.init_app(app)` inside the factory. Don't know if that's the answer but is something that stands out to me.

Comment: @SuperShoot the error still persists, thank you though!

Comment: @APorter1031 did you manage to solve this?? but how exactly?

Comment: @SaqibMujtaba I was able to get better results with the `wtforms` package but am still working on a solution...